# simple javascript regular expression in for loop

Tags: javascript, regex

This is driving me nuts, but I can't make this very simple regular expression work. I have a JSON object, and I am trying to sum all of the properties that start with `"eehrs_"` (the values for these properties are all integers). Just to debug it, I am trying to simply print out the property name to show that the loop is working. Here is the regular expression and loop I am using. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
for (i = 0; i < schoolJSON.features.length; i++) {
    for (property in schoolJSON.features[i].properties) {
        if (property == /(eehrs_\d+)|(eehrs_[p|k])/) { 
            console.log(property);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I tried using a simple `/^eehrs_/`, but that did not work either.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong:

```
if (/^eehrs_(?:\d+|[pk])/.test(property)) {
    ...
```

You don't have to test if a string *is* a regular expression, but rather you use the regex to [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) the string.